# How to create a sub domain to point to Cloudfront CDN endpoint using a domain managed outside of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

We purchased a domain from GoDaddy, for example, say `mycompany.com`.

My colleague then moved it to Wix.com to publish our marketing site, which will be available at the `mycompany.com` url. I need to add a subdomain in AWS, pointing to a Cloudfront CDN endpoint.

To shed more light into the current situation, here is a little more info:

When I check GoDaddy, it shows Nameservers, referencing the Wix servers. For DNS, it says `We can't display your DNS information because your Nameservers aren't managed by us.`

When I check Wix.com, I see that `Managed by Third Party, Connected by DNS` and still provides the option to transfer to Wix.

Both Godaddy and Wix provide the option to add a subdomain.

I'd rather do that in AWS.

What is my best option here? Should I transfer the domain to AWS and manage it there? If so, how do I then route traffic from `mycompany.com` to the marketing site?

Is there a way to keep it as is, but still add a subdomain on the AWS side for `example.mycompany.com`?

I really regret not registering this domain via AWS in the first place, but lesson learned. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So to confirm your nameserver is pointed at wix, but you cannot modify any DNS records from wix.com?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams it looks like I can modify DNS records in Wix. The confusing part for me was the option to transfer still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your DNS is being hosted via wix.com.

If you want to migrate to Route 53 its not actually too hard. Start by setting up a public hosted zone within Route 53 with the domain name you setup.

Next you would want to perform a zone lookup for all your DNS records, you can use Googles [DIG Tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#ANY/) with the `ANY` option or do this via cli by running `dig example.com ANY`.

Now that you have all the records you will need to create them within your public hosted zone, [follow this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html) if you need any assistance. Do **not add** the `SOA` or `NS` records.

Now that all records have been migrated get the values from the `NS` record in your public hosted zone and replace the nameservers within GoDaddy to point at these values.

Your DNS will migrate over whichever period the TTL of your previous `NS` record is set as. Once this has migrated and it working you can add your `CNAME` record as you originally wanted to add.

Comment: thanks for responding. So from what I see here, this will update the GoDaddy Nameservers to point to my AWS public record set. And then I would need to point my public record set to the Wix Nameservers to make sure that the marketing site still routes to that? At this point the subdomain is straight forward but I want to be sure about the marketing site.

Comment: The records for your marketing site (in wix) would be migrated to Route 53. No NameServers just the A or CNAME records for the domain :)

Comment: Thanks @Chris Williams, my subdomains are working just fine right now. I'll reach back out if I have trouble with the marketing site (yet to publish) but the main goal is achieved with your answer

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)